# Python. Как написать функцию в одну строку (список в строку , тернарный if и return)

Tags: python

хочу написать функцию функцию, которая будет проверять вхождение слова из списка в строку. Рабочий вариант:

```
def compaign_type(row, list_search):
    for x in list_search:
        if x in row:
            return x
```

что пробовал:

```
def compaign_type(row, list_search):    
    return x if x in row for x in list_search
```

Возможно вообще подобное сочетание?

***UPDATE:***

row = 'aa_bb_cc'

list_search = ['aa', 'dd', 'ss']

Comment: Напишите пример `row` и `list_search`.

Answer (score 1):

Надеюсь Вы перестанете редактировать вопрос. Вы тернарный оператор удаляете постоянно.

В текущем состоянии:

```python
def compaign_type(row, list_search):
    for x in list_search:
        if x in row:
            return x
compaign_type('aa_bb_cc', ['aa', 'dd', 'ss'])
```

###### Вывод:

```console
'aa'
```

В одну строку:

```python
compaign_type = lambda r, l: next(iter([x for x in l if x in r]), None)
compaign_type('aa_bb_cc', ['aa', 'dd', 'ss'])
```

###### Вывод:

```console
'aa'
```

Альтеративно с `def`:

```python
def compaign_type(r, l): return next(iter([x for x in l if x in r]), None)
```

Comment: `....[0] or None`

Comment: @eri `None` надо предусмотреть, Вы правы. Но наверное [иначе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363944/python-idiom-to-return-first-item-or-none).